# Function that reads a file and parses it into dictionary

Tags: python, file, parsing, dictionary

Write a function, parse, that takes a filename and parses each line using the comma-separated values format into a dictionary of dictionaries. The example file given is:

```
id,age,name
100,31,George
101,47,Herbert
103,72,Harriet
```

The expected output dictionary would be:

```
{'103': {'name': 'Harriet', 'age': '72', 'id': '103'}, '100': {'name': 
'George', 'age': '31', 'id': '100'}, '101': {'name': 'Herbert', 'age': '47', 
'id': '101'}}
```

Make sure to use the .strip() method of string to remove the end of line character from each line you parse.

Hint: You should paste in your data_dictionary function from the previous question and call it from your parse function to help with each line.

For example:

Test    Result

```
print(sorted(d["100"].items()))= = [('age', '31'), ('id', '100'), ('name', 'George')]
print(sorted(d["101"].items()))= [('age', '47'), ('id', '101'), ('name', 'Herbert')]
print(sorted(d["103"].items())) = [('age', '72'), ('id', '103'), ('name', 'Harriet')]
```

This is my code that i have. Data_dictionary is perfect, but need parse. Please help cannot figure it out!

```
def data_dictionary(keys,values):

    d = {}
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        d[keys[i]] = values[i]
    return d


def parse(file):

    d = {}
    with open(file) as file_name:
        for line in file_name:
            keys = (item.strip() for item in line.split(','))
        for line in file_name:
            values = (item.strip() for item in line.split('/n'))
            data_dictionary(keys,values)
            return d
```

Comment: You have `id` as primary key so why do you need to add it to the body of the dictionary?

Comment: Why do you have 2 loops ? Just read the first line to get keys then loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing weird things with generator expressions.  This is a csv file.  Use the csv module to read it.

```
import csv

def parse(file):
    d = {}
    with open(file) as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        _ = next(r) #consume the headers
        for line in r:
            d.update({d[0]: {'age': d[1], 'name':d[2]}})

    return d
```

Or we could use `csv.DictReader`

```
def parse(file):
    d = {}
    with open(file) as f:
        r = csv.DictReader(f)
        for line in r:
            id = line.pop('id')
            d.update({id: line})
    return d
```